# How to render different content in React based on the route from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, routes

I am working on a website for multiple stores. They would be at addresses such as: `https://address/Store1/`, `https://address/Store2/` etc.
I want to do the routing separation in the backend and based on the URL parameter (`Store1`, `Store2`), to render a different React component or just to return different data to the frontend somehow.

So far I have:

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "store",
        pattern: "Store/{action=Index}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Store" }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

**StoreController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     return Json("Please specify a store");
}

public ActionResult Store1() {
     return View("Store1");
}

public ActionResult Store2() {
     return View("Store2");
}
```

Where `Store1` and `Store2` are React components (`Store1.tsx`, `Store2.tsx`). But in this case, the program expects the view to be a `.html`/`.cshtml` file.

The end question is how to render different content in React based on the route from ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Are you looking for client-side routing? You can use various React-compatible routing libraries to do that.

Comment: You can output JavaScript from the page and change the rendering of the React app through that. You can initialize it with a variable that says where to go. Depends on whether you use routing or something else how exactly it would be done.

Comment: @juunas, I want to do the routing in ASP.NET

Comment: This is a spa, right @AN00?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen but still, how would you get that variable from StoreController, not knowing in advance which action will be called?

Comment: @MKougiouris, yes

Comment: i got you... let me write some things

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, since this is SPA you are thinking about it in a wrong.

You can not ( and in any case you do not want to ) have the .net server fetching plain small components.

You can not avoid the client side routing, in fact the app that you are making should be a complete, client-only react-based SPA, with routing added on the client.

There problem you are having is that when you ask the server for say "/Stores/1" from within the app, for example a navigation link, everything plays nicely i guess, because all components are bundled on the delivered SPA app.
But when you try to share a link, or to directly hit "www.host.com/stores/1" from a new tab, the server would not know what to do with it... your SPA is served from 1 point, and it has 1 starting state.

What you need to do, is to add routing on the client app, and just as i.e:

- [www.host.com](http://www.host.com) => returns the SPA app
- [www.host.com/Stores/1](http://www.host.com/Stores/1) => should return again the same SPA, but with a new starting state.

"Handling the routing on .net" should only mean "how to handle detail routes, instead of just serving the same entry point, when someone asks the .net server directly, instead of navigating from within the applications client-side router ( which directs what gets rendered ).

In essence, since this is a SPA, "ALL ROUTES EXCEP THE ROOT ROUTE, SHOULD DELIVER THE SAME SPA BUT WITH A DIFFERENT STARTING STATE".

I have recently implemented a react front end, with a .net core back-end (apis & SPA serving ) and the above method works great!

Comment: This makes sense if I want to navigate to Store1 and Store2 from within the same page, but I want to be able to access them as separate pages, as you said, directly hitting them from a new tab. So in this case, the routing should be done on backend side, no?

Comment: well not rly... because the "routing" that we are talking about is like i.e:
rootURL => return app.js and wait for user
Stores/1 => return app.js, use the javascript's side, client router and push "Stores/1" react-router
Some/Other/Uri=> return app.js, have javascript push "Some/Other/Uri" in the react-router

Comment: Its a simple idea rly. If route "/" delivers app.js and await, then the .net controller for "Stores/1" should return the same exact spa, and just push the route in the client's router